# Exporting ES6 and React as a AMD module with webpack or babel-cli

Tags: php, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, amd

EDIT 2: Solved it, with a slight modification to the accepted answer, now my `webpack.config.js` looks like so:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        adminpanel: path.join(__dirname, 'theme/peakbalance/es6/adminpanel.js')
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'theme/peakbalance/amd/src'),
        filename: '[name]_bundle.js',
        libraryTarget: 'amd'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test:/\.(js|jsx)$/,
            loader:'babel',
            query: {
                presets: ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

So i have been struggling with this issue for quite some time now. I am coding in a old php system called moodle, which are tightly coupled with the AMD system, i would like to use new JS technologies instead of jquery 1.12 like react, immutable, redux etc. though, so i am trying to make the last part of the build chain export an AMD module. What i have right now:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
entry: {
    adminpanel: path.join(__dirname, 'theme/peakbalance/amd/es6/adminpanel.js')
},
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'theme/peakbalance/amd/src'),
    filename: '[name]_bundle.js'
},
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test:/\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader:'babel',
        query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react'],
            plugins: ['transform-es2015-modules-amd']
        },
        include:path.join(__dirname,'./theme/peakbalance/amd/es6')
    }, {
        test:/\.json$/,
        loaders:['json-loader'],
        include:path.join(__dirname,'./theme/peakbalance/amd/es6')
    }, {
        test:/\.(png|jpg)$/,
        loader:'url?limit=25000'
    }, {
        test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "file"
    }, {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2)/,
        loader:"url?prefix=font/&limit=5000"
    }, {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream"
    }, {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml"
    }]
  }
};
```

So as you can see, i am trying to use a transform-es2015-modules-amd plugin for the loader, this plugin works perfect if i use it together with the babel-cli like this:

```
babel --plugins transform-es2015-modules-amd ./theme/peakbalance/es6/adminpanel.js
```

then it outputs:

```
define(["exports"], function (exports) {
        "use strict";

        Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
            value: true
        });

        function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
            if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
                throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function");
            }
        }

        var _createClass = function () {
            function defineProperties(target, props) {
                for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
                    var descriptor = props[i];
                    descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false;
                    descriptor.configurable = true;
                    if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true;
                    Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor);
                }
            }

            return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {
                if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps);
                if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps);
                return Constructor;
            };
        }();

        var AdminPanel = function () {
            function AdminPanel() {
                _classCallCheck(this, AdminPanel);

                this.init = this.init.bind(this);
            }

            _createClass(AdminPanel, [{
                key: "init",
                value: function init(herpderp) {
                    console.log("herpderp42424");
                    console.log("herp");
                    var app = new App();
                }
            }]);

            return AdminPanel;
        }();

        exports.default = AdminPanel;
    });
});
```

When its being run through webpack with just:

```
webpack -w
```

it outputs:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};

/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            exports: {},
/******/            id: moduleId,
/******/            loaded: false
/******/        };

/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.loaded = true;

/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }


/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;

/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";

/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    export default class AdminPanel {
            constructor() {
                this.init = this.init.bind(this);
            }
            init(herpderp) {
                console.log("herpderp42424");
                console.log("herp");
                console.log("alright alright");
                let app = new App();
            }
        }
/***/ }
/******/ ]);
```

So now it doesn't even transpile it from es6 to es5 and its absolutely not a AMD module structure.

I basically just want the exact same behavior as the babel cli, but with webpack doing its magic, since i'll probably go beyond 1 file, so i need the files to be concatted, i looked at something like the babel-plugin-inline-import plugin, that i would be able to use with the babel-cli for multiple files, but i really think that webpack is more smooth. Have anyone fixed this issue??

EDIT 1: I have changed my webpack configuration to something simplified like so:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
     adminpanel: path.join(__dirname, 'theme/peakbalance/es6/adminpanel.js')
  },
  output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'theme/peakbalance/amd/src'),
      filename: '[name]_bundle.js',
      library: 'amd'
  },
  module: {
      loaders: [{
          test:/\.(js|jsx)$/,
          loader:'babel',
          query: {
              presets: ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"]
          }
      }]
    }
 };
```

And now atleast webpack is transpileing it to the following:

```
var amd =
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};

/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            exports: {},
/******/            id: moduleId,
/******/            loaded: false
/******/        };

/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.loaded = true;

/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }


/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;

/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";

/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    "use strict";

    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
        value: true
    });

    var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

    function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

    var AdminPanel = function () {
        function AdminPanel() {
            _classCallCheck(this, AdminPanel);

            this.init = this.init.bind(this);
        }

        _createClass(AdminPanel, [{
            key: "init",
            value: function init(herpderp) {
                console.log("herpderp42424");
                console.log("herp");
                console.log("alright alright");
                var app = new App();
            }
        }]);

        return AdminPanel;
    }();

    exports.default = AdminPanel;

/***/ }
/******/ ]);
```

But setting a variable called amd  equal to what im exporting, is hardly a substitute for a Define call according to the AMD standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is happening is babel transforms to AMD and then Webpack transforms AMD into __webpack_require__ ready for the browser.

What you probably want to do is ditch the `transform-es2015-modules-amd` plugin and update your Webpack config to include `output.libraryTarget = 'amd'`. Then Webpack will export the entire bundle as AMD.

https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-library

Comment: As soon as i have time, im going to test that, looks easy if that actually works :-)

Comment: Hi, i tried it now, and i updated my question with the attempt, its not giving me a AMD module though, its just giving me a  variable called amd and sets the export equal to that, i dont know why that makes sense. i tried with uppercase amd aswell and nothing changed.

Comment: Okay. i read the documentation, and output.libraryTarget : 'amd' worked, library didn't quite cut it. Thanks alot  !!! i would've spend hours on this and weird solutions.

Comment: @DenLilleMand ah yes I meant `libraryTarget`, glad to hear you got it working!